# First timers database schema for a MySQL database

Tags: database, relational, server

I'm looking for some critical feedback on a relational database design I made for a project.
The database is needed for a 2nd year CS project at my school but we have not yet had any teachings on this subject so help is much appreciated.

The database needs to consist of tables such as shopping lists, Users, wares etc. which needs to be shared and updated between units.

As can be seen in the design every user is related to many shoppinglists and likewise mealplans and both of those are also related to groups. Users must also be related to groups and each row in UserGroup linking table has a role as Users must have a role in their group relations.

1. Is this a structurally sound design?
2. Is it  inadvisable to have columns besides foreign keys in a linking table?

Thanks for your time and help!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqHf6.png Full size picture of design schema
[image: Design schema]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's looks good.

```
Q> Is this a structurally sound design?
A> Yes
Q> Is it inadvisable to have columns besides foreign keys in a linking table?
A> It's common to have additional columns
```

Be careful, don't over-normalize. 
Sometimes it's wise to have 1 table with duplicates records, than 10 tables join.

best regards

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback, in the group we made a revised schema where table has 2 foreign keys is that even possible? [link](http://imgur.com/pvXI6uQ)

Comment: it's completely normal to have multiple FK.

Comment: Thanks i forgot to add that it was multiple foreign keys for a non linking table but i assume the answer is the same. Thanks for the help mate!!